# Place icons on right end of accordion

Tags: html, css, materialize

I've made the following collapsible accordion with the use of  Materialize css framework.

I'm trying to place the chevron icons at the end of collapsible header. I have applied css class right to make icon float to the right end of the collapsible header but this doesn't make it go complete right end of the collapsible header.

What would be the best measure to move the chevron icon to the right end position of collapsible header.

```js
 $('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

```css
.collapsible li.active i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
      
      First
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Second
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Third
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it absolute

```
.collapsible-header i {

    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```js
$('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

```css
.collapsible li.active i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.collapsible-header i {
    
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
      
      First
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Second
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Third
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

As your `div.collapsible-header` already has `display:flex`, you can add `justify-content: space-between`. This will make...

> the first item is flush with the main-start edge, and the last item is flush with the main-end edge.

[justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

```js
$('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

```css
.collapsible li.active i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.collapsible-header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">

      First
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">Second
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">Third
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice answer :tup:

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `row`, and `col` (Grid Structure) like this:

```js
$('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

```css
.collapsible li.active i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.collapsible-header.row {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header row">
      
      <div class="col s11">First</div>
      <i class="col s1 material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header row"><div class="col s11">Second</div>
      <i class="col s1 material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header row"><div class="col s11">Third</div>
      <i class="col s1 material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **"justify-content: space-between;"** to the class **'collapsible-header'**.

```js
 $('.collapsible').collapsible();
```

```css
.collapsible li.active i {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
.collapsible-header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
      
      First
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Second
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Third
      <i class="material-icons rotate right">expand_more</i></div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I think Its like @ksav answer?

Comment: Yes, I have also added the answer at the same time. After that he made some edits.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added a "display: block" to the collapsible-header and it worked fine...

```css
.collapsible-header{
    display: block;
}
```

and add only right class to material icon. it will work